# $_SESSION is not getting populated in Yii 1.1 for custom session implementation

Tags: php, session, yii

I have recently been asked to work on a legacy code base written using `Yii 1.1` and `Php 5.3`. We have a custome session implementation calling a rest api. The code looks something like below:-

```
CSessionService extends CHTTPSession {

    public function open()
    {
        Session::setJSessionId();
        parent::open();
    }

    public function getUseCustomStorage()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function regenerateID($deleteOldSession=false)
    {
        Session::setRegeneratedSessionId(
            SessionServiceAdapter::getInstance()->generateSessionId(), $deleteOldSession
        );

    }

    public function readSession($id)
    {
        return SessionServiceAdapter::getInstance()->getSessionData($id);
    }

    public function writeSession($id,$data)
    {
        return SessionServiceAdapter::getInstance()->replaceSession($id, $this->toArray());

    }

    public function destroySession($id)
    {
        if($id!=='')
        {
            SessionServiceAdapter::getInstance()->deleteSession($id);
            @session_unset();
            @session_destroy();

        }
    }
}
```

The helper session class looks like below:-

```
class Core_Session
{
    protected static $_cache = array();

    public static function generateId()
    {
        session_regenerate_id(false);
    }

    public static function add($key, $data)
    {
        self::$_cache[$key] = $data;
        if ($data instanceof Transfer_Interface) {
            $data = array(
            'class' => get_class($data),
            'data' => $data->toArray()
            );
        }
        Yii::app()->session->add($key, $data);
    }

    public static function get($key)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$_cache[$key])) {
            $data = Yii::app()->session->get($key);
            if (is_array($data) && array_key_exists('class', $data)) {
                $className = $data['class'];
                $data = new $className($data['data']);
            }
            self::$_cache[$key] = $data;
            return $data;

        } else {
            return self::$_cache[$key];
        }
    }

    public static function remove($key)
    {
        $value = Yii::app()->session->remove($key);
        if (isset(self::$_cache[$key])) {
            unset(self::$_cache[$key]);
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public static function isRegistered($key)
    {
        if (isset(self::$_cache[$key])) {
            return true;
        }
        $result = in_array($key, Yii::app()->session->getKeys());
        return $result;
    }

    public static function getId()
    {
        return Yii::app()->session->sessionID;
    }

    public static function generateSessionId($customerId = null)
    {

            return SessionServiceAdapter::getInstance()->generateSessionId();

    }

     public static function setJSessionId() {
        session_id(static::generateSessionId());
     }
}
```

The `autostart` is set to true.  I am facing a problem in which after Session open I am not seeing the `$_SESSION` getting populated even though `readSession` is getting called. Also `session_start` is called before trying to access `$_SESSION`?

Can someone let me know what could be going wrong? Why `$_SESSION` is not getting populated?

If I modify my `readSession` like below:-

```
public function readSession($id)
    {
        $val = SessionServiceAdapter::getInstance()->getSessionData($id);
        $_SESSION = $val;
        return $val;
    }
```

Then I am seeing `$_SESSION` is populated. But after going over the documentation of Yii it appears to me that I should not be explicitly setting `$_SESSION`. That Yii should automatically do if I am calling `session_start` before accessing `$_SESSION`.